# Showing line numbers by default in ed

Tags: editors, ed, line

In the `ex` editor, one can show line numbers by default by adding this line to a `.exrc` file:

```
set number
```

Is there a way to have `ed` start with line numbers showing by default, when lines are invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.  You have to remember to use the `n` command in place of `p` when looking at lines, or in place of `.` when looking at the current line, or to add `n` in places when the default is to print a line without line number (if allowed).

If you use the `z` command to look at portions of the buffer at a time, e.g. 10 lines at a time from line 1 with `1z10` and then `z` repeatedly to see the next 10 lines etc., then instead use `1z10n` and `zn` to do the same thing with line numbers.

You can get the `s///` command to print the result of a substitution with a line number using `s///n`.

Use `g/re/n` in place of `g/re/p` to get numbering of the lines that matches the regular expression `re`.

It all comes down to getting used to using `n` when needed.